# Can "darling" be used as an adjective in the sentence "You look so darling"?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, word-usage

I've never heard of the word "darling" being used this way until yesterday, and a discussion came up about whether this would be correct use or not.

Edit: Some additional info I wrote in reply to an answer:

Googling phrases such as ["you look darling"](https://www.google.com/search?q="you+look+darling"), ["you look so darling"](https://www.google.com/search?q="you+look+so+darling"), and ["you look very darling"](https://www.google.com/search?q="you+look+very+darling") does bring up various instances of the word being used in this way. It still doesn't make sense to me, but it does seem to be a way people use the word.

Comment: Your edit should actually go in an answer rather than in the question!

Comment: @ruakh So by answering my own question or by replyinh to the answer the other person made?

Comment: I would put it in a separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

According to Collins Dictionary, 'darling' as an adjective has two meanings:
1. Dearly loved.
2. Very pleasing.
 'To look darling' means 'to  look charming'.
So your sentence is correct.

Comment: In my experience, this usage is most likely to be used for children—"doesn't (s)he look darling!" is the archetypal sentence in my mind. It also strikes me as a slightly twee term, but that's probably dependent on local culture.

Comment: 1006a, Thank you for your interesting comment.

Comment: I had to look up ***twee***

Comment: 'Twee' is a baby corruption of 'sweet'. According to Etymology Online,  it is attested in the 1990s .

Comment: "Rough winds do shake the darling buds of May" Sonnet 18 (William Shakespeare).